# Is std::vector<int, std::allocator<char> > valid?

Tags: c++, gcc, vector, allocator

The standard says nothing about the allocator of `std::vector` but only requires the allocator to satisfy the `Allocator` concept. Nothing about the allocator's value_type, no reference_type, no nothing.

I thought `std::vector<T, A>` internally rebinds `A` to an allocator for `T`, so I gave a vector `std::allocator<char>` and it worked as expected.

However, GCC generates errors if `std::allocator<void>` is given, as below:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/ext/alloc_traits.h: In instantiation of ‘struct __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<void> >’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_vector.h:75:28:   required from ‘struct std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<void> >’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_vector.h:214:11:   required from ‘class std::vector<int, std::allocator<void> >’
a.cpp:5:42:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/ext/alloc_traits.h:109:53: error: forming reference to void
     typedef value_type&                             reference;
                                                 ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.2/include/g++-v4/ext/alloc_traits.h:110:53: error: forming reference to void
     typedef const value_type&                       const_reference;
                                                 ^
```

Is it a GCC's bug? or am I misreading the standard?

- GCC version : 4.9.2

Comment: Even on implementations where it isn't necessary for the allocator's value_type to match the vector element type, you do have to pass a valid allocator.  `std::allocator<void>` isn't valid, as the template argument is required to be "a non-const object type" and `void` is not.

Comment: @BenVoigt There's an explicit specialization of `std::allocator` for `void`.

Comment: @T.C.: Right, but it is an allocator factory, not an allocator.  `allocator_traits` fails miserably with `allocator<void>`

Comment: [libstdc++ does intentionally support `std::vector<int, std::allocator<char>>`](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64865#c3), though, so I wonder if breaking on `allocator<void>` is an oversight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not allowed. First row of table 99:

[image: Table 99]

Comment: Why couldn't `allocator_type` be defined via rebinding by the container?

Comment: @dyp In theory it can. But the standard defines the `allocator_type` typedef to be identical to the `Allocator` template argument for individual containers.

Comment: @dyp: Because it is a template argument.  The container could (and often does, for metadata) use a rebound version of allocator_type, but it cannot redefine allocator_type.

Comment: @BenVoigt There's nothing in theory that prevents the standard from saying that `allocator_type` is `typename allocator_traits<Allocator>::template rebind_alloc<value_type>`. It just doesn't do it.

Comment: @T.C.: Sure, but it doesn't.  And it doesn't leave the flexibility for the implementer to do so.  It does leave the flexibility for the implementer to use a rebound version of the allocator for actual allocation.